# mongodb find with opposite of $elemMatch

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection like this:

```
posts = {
  title: 'Hey',
  content: '...',
  authors: [{
    id: 'id',
    name: 'John'
  }, {
    id: 'id2',
    name: 'david'
  }]
};
```

I want to make a query. I have found the $elementMatch, but I would like the opposite.

I have also found $nin but I don't if it works for mycase.

Here is what I want to do:

```
db.posts.find({
  authors: {
    $notElemMatch: {
      id: 'id'
    }
  }
});
```

I want to find every posts except those writing by someone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't even need [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) since you only have a single field condition. Just use [`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) instead:

```
db.posts.find({ "authors.id": { "$ne": 'id' } });
```

There is a [`$not`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) condition, but it really does not need apply here.

Comment: @sergiopereira You are incorrect. The statement here would "correctly" select only documents where **no** `"authors.id"` value matches the value supplied. That is exactly what the OP asks. Therefore since the data contains `"id"` as one of the entries the "post" would not be returned. You don't need `$elemMatch` for a single condition. I think you a confused in thinking that you return the "array" content "filtered" by that value. That is of course a completely different case to selecting the "post". Which is what the question asks.

Comment: @sergiopereira Perhaps you should not have been so quick to downvote as well. It's also not a great idea to voice such and opionion or act in that way unless you can actually prove a case. `$elemMatch` in particular is misquoted and misused on a regular basis. So if you are going to have a critique about someones response, then you'd best have a better working answer first.

Comment: @sergiopereira Not arguing but pointing out the error in how you are approaching things. And of course you can undo the downvote. There is only a grace period in which you cannot. But that is passed.

Comment: While you did answer for the specific case of the OP you did not answer the question he really asked. So everybody getting here who really is searching for the opposite of `$elemMatch` (in more complex cases than OP's) is left with no answer.
Actually answering the question as well as pointing out OP will not need it, would have been nice.

Answer (score 1):

While the original question does not require the use of `$elemMatch` (as answered by Blakes), here is one way to "invert" the `$elemMatch` operator.

Use `$filter` + `$and` as a subsitute for `$elemMatch` and check that the result has 0 length.
`$expr` allows the use of aggregation expressions in simple "find" queries.

All conditions in `$elemMatch` will be translated to items in the array supplied as an argument to `$and`.

*Tested to work with MongoDB server version 5.0.9*

```
{
  "$expr": {
    "$eq": [
      {
        "$size": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$authors",
            "cond": {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "$eq": ["$$this.id", "id"]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      0
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better way to "invert" the `$elemMatch` operator with aggregation.

Use `$expr` `$eq` and `$in`

`$in` checks if the item is in the array, since we want opposite meaning `false` so we check if the result of the "$in" operation is `$eq` (equal) to false

```
{
  "$expr": {
    "$eq": [{ "$in": { 'id', "authors.id"} }, false]
  }
}
```